# Plot different colours - Scilab

Tags: plot, colors, scilab

Is it possible to have different colours in my plot in Scilab? I use the  `mtlb_hold` to hold the graph and it works fine, but my problem is that then I have the same colours in my graph. In Matlab with the `hold` command, I have different colours. Is it possible to have different colours in Scilab too?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found it. In the `plot` function, for example `plot()`, you can pass a second argument which specifies the color that will be used. For example, you can use use `b` for blue color, `g` for green, `r` for red and call `plot()` like this: `plot(z,"r")`.

Answer (score 2):

The SciLab documentation provides examples for using colors:
https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/color.html

The `plot2d()`-function e.g. accepts an attribute style, where you can even specify a color for each function with its full name:

```
plot2d(x,[sin(x),cos(x)],style=[color("red"),color("green")]);
```